Graphql Hotchocolate authorization exception in unit tests
I am getting an authorization exception from Hot chocolate libraries while executing this test question.
This is similar to this few of the existing posts on hot chocolate authorization exception in integration tests.
The main difference is that the class QueryRequestBuilder is no longer available in the latest Hot chocolate libraries, so instead using the OperationRequestBuilder.
var schema = await services
    .AddGraphQLServer()
    .ModifyRequestOptions(opt => opt.IncludeExceptionDetails = true) 
    .ModifyCostOptions(x => x.EnforceCostLimits = false)
    .AddAuthorization() 
    .AddQueryType(q => q.Name("Query"))
    .AddType<Query>()
    .AddFiltering()
    .BuildSchemaAsync();
var executor = schema.MakeExecutable();
var query = @"{}";
var request = OperationRequestBuilder.New()
    .SetDocument(query)
    .SetServices(services.BuildServiceProvider())
    .AddGlobalState(nameof(ClaimsPrincipal), CreatePrincipal()).Build();

var result = await executor.ExecuteAsync(request);
result.MatchSnapshot();

private static ClaimsPrincipal CreatePrincipal()
{
    var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal();
    var claimIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] { new Claim("appid", "appid") });
    claimsPrincipal.AddIdentity(claimIdentity);
    return claimsPrincipal;
}

I am trying to resolve the autorization exception with the hot chocolate libraries.
